# How to combine 3 columns from 3 different tables into one filter

Tags: filter, powerbi

I am new to PowerBI and learning.

I have 3 different tables coming in from sql to powerbi. All tables have the same columns.

On my PowerBI page, I have 3 different tables each showing the same thing: sales, YoY sales, orders, YoY orders, AOV, YoY AOV.

1 table looks at coupons, another looks at coupons by initial channel and the third looks at overall.

I would like to have 2 filters: StoreID and OrderMonth that update all 3 tables opposed to just one. Right now it seems I can only accomplish this by using 6 filters, 2 per table. Is there a way to set it so that I can have 1 StoreID filter that updates all 3 tables?

Answer (score 0):

If all the tables have the same columns you can use PowerQuery (M) to pre-process the data.

To each table, add a new column, (say) Type. Set that column as a calculated column to "coupons",  "coupons by channel" and "overall".

Then merge the the three tables in to one master table.

On your visual/s, you can then filter by the Type. If you want to get a little more fancy, you can perform dimension extraction to separate out the Type. Alternatively you can keep the tables separate and investigate [shared dimensions](https://radacad.com/creating-a-shared-dimension-in-power-bi-using-power-query-basics-and-foundations-of-modeling).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a table which has all the distinct storeids and order month from the three tables. Once the table is created, create a relationship between the new table and all the other tables. Now, you can use the fields from the new table in a slicer and it should filter all three tables. Hope this helps.